# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.servlet.PortalSessionActivationListener on Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, liferay, weblogic, weblogic11g

I have Liferay installed on Weblogic 10.3.6. When I start the server, only the first time I proceed with the login process I get the following error:

```
(Wrapped) java.io.IOException: readObject failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.servlet.PortalSessionActivationListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:603)
at com.tangosol.io.ResolvingObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ResolvingObjectInputStream.java:66)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.readSerializable(ExternalizableHelper.java:2217)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.readObjectInternal(ExternalizableHelper.java:2348)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.deserializeInternal(ExternalizableHelper.java:2746)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.fromBinary(ExternalizableHelper.java:262)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.OptimizedHolder.deserializeValue(OptimizedHolder.java:233)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.OptimizedHolder.getValue(OptimizedHolder.java:64)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.SplittableHolder.getValue(SplittableHolder.java:56)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.AbstractHttpSessionModel.activate(AbstractHttpSessionModel.java:737)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.AbstractHttpSessionCollection.activate(AbstractHttpSessionCollection.java:830)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionData$HttpSessionImpl.ensureActiveModel(CoherenceWebSessionData.java:489)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.api23.HttpSessionImpl.getCreationTime(HttpSessionImpl.java:122)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionData.<init>(CoherenceWebSessionData.java:118)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPIFactory.instantiateHttpSession(WebLogicSPIFactory.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPIFactory.instantiateHttpSession(WebLogicSPIFactory.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPISessionHelper.ensureHttpSession(WebLogicSPISessionHelper.java:174)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.retrieveSession(CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.java:707)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.getSessionInternal(CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.java:650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.updateSessionId(ServletRequestImpl.java:3031)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.generateNewSession(SecurityModule.java:319)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.login(SecurityModule.java:306)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.processJSecurityCheck(FormSecurityModule.java:302)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkUserPerm(FormSecurityModule.java:213)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkAccess(FormSecurityModule.java:96)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.ServletSecurityManager.checkAccess(ServletSecurityManager.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2209)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)


ClassLoader: weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@419b1b finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@1c1a0bd annotation: soggetto-posizioneinformativa-fe-jbus-portafogliocliente-ear@soggetto-posizioneinformativa-fe-jbus-portafogliocliente-web-web
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.fromBinary(ExternalizableHelper.java:266)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.OptimizedHolder.deserializeValue(OptimizedHolder.java:233)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.OptimizedHolder.getValue(OptimizedHolder.java:64)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.SplittableHolder.getValue(SplittableHolder.java:56)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.AbstractHttpSessionModel.activate(AbstractHttpSessionModel.java:737)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.AbstractHttpSessionCollection.activate(AbstractHttpSessionCollection.java:830)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionData$HttpSessionImpl.ensureActiveModel(CoherenceWebSessionData.java:489)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.api23.HttpSessionImpl.getCreationTime(HttpSessionImpl.java:122)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionData.(CoherenceWebSessionData.java:118)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPIFactory.instantiateHttpSession(WebLogicSPIFactory.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPIFactory.instantiateHttpSession(WebLogicSPIFactory.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPISessionHelper.ensureHttpSession(WebLogicSPISessionHelper.java:174)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.retrieveSession(CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.java:707)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.getSessionInternal(CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.java:650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.updateSessionId(ServletRequestImpl.java:3031)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.generateNewSession(SecurityModule.java:319)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.login(SecurityModule.java:306)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.processJSecurityCheck(FormSecurityModule.java:302)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkUserPerm(FormSecurityModule.java:213)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkAccess(FormSecurityModule.java:96)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.ServletSecurityManager.checkAccess(ServletSecurityManager.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2209)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: readObject failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.servlet.PortalSessionActivationListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:603)
at com.tangosol.io.ResolvingObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ResolvingObjectInputStream.java:66)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.readSerializable(ExternalizableHelper.java:2217)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.readObjectInternal(ExternalizableHelper.java:2348)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.deserializeInternal(ExternalizableHelper.java:2746)
at com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.fromBinary(ExternalizableHelper.java:262)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.OptimizedHolder.deserializeValue(OptimizedHolder.java:233)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.OptimizedHolder.getValue(OptimizedHolder.java:64)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.SplittableHolder.getValue(SplittableHolder.java:56)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.AbstractHttpSessionModel.activate(AbstractHttpSessionModel.java:737)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.AbstractHttpSessionCollection.activate(AbstractHttpSessionCollection.java:830)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionData$HttpSessionImpl.ensureActiveModel(CoherenceWebSessionData.java:489)
at com.tangosol.coherence.servlet.api23.HttpSessionImpl.getCreationTime(HttpSessionImpl.java:122)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionData.<init>(CoherenceWebSessionData.java:118)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPIFactory.instantiateHttpSession(WebLogicSPIFactory.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPIFactory.instantiateHttpSession(WebLogicSPIFactory.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.WebLogicSPISessionHelper.ensureHttpSession(WebLogicSPISessionHelper.java:174)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.retrieveSession(CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.java:707)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.getSessionInternal(CoherenceWebSessionContextImpl.java:650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.updateSessionId(ServletRequestImpl.java:3031)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.generateNewSession(SecurityModule.java:319)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.login(SecurityModule.java:306)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.processJSecurityCheck(FormSecurityModule.java:302)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkUserPerm(FormSecurityModule.java:213)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkAccess(FormSecurityModule.java:96)
at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.ServletSecurityManager.checkAccess(ServletSecurityManager.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2209)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I am a newbie about using Liferay and Weblogic. I am working in a company and we are facing with this problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your manifest file and do a maven clean install. Pretty sure that the package is not imported in your manifest. If this problem continues then import the package manually and investigate as to why isn't it getting pulled in on its own.